# Accessing properties in objects created by constructors

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, this

I have a for loop like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  obj[i] = new MapArea(some passed variables);
}
```

Now this constructor has a few predefined properties as well as some defined at initialization. As the for loop would suggest, each obj is held inside it's own index within the array obj[]. My issue is that after I have iterated through initialization, I cannot reference the properties of individual objects with a

```
this.propertyName;
```

or

```
$(this).propertyName;
```

The plugin I am building operates off mouse events (clicks and hovers) meaning I need to be able to check the obj attached to the event for specific properties on it's current state but have no way of programmatically knowing what index it is in the array to reference it, or at least doing so easily and concisely.

Has anyone encountered this problem and found a solution or am I pretty much forced into using the array and index as a reference? Any help would be awesome.

here is one of my methods for example:

```
$.fn.clickLight = function(options) {
  var defaults = $.extend( {
    color : "#43464B",
    opacity : "0.3"
  }, options);
  ctx.globalAlpha = defaults.opacity;

  $(area_ref).click(function(event) {
    $(this).handleMouse(event).each(function() {
      if (!$(this).clicked) { // I try and access here
        console.log(obj.this.clicked);
        $(this).highlight(defaults.color);
        $(this).clicked = true;
      } else {
        console.log(this.clicked);
        $(this).clearlight();
        $(this).clicked = false;
      }
    } );
  } );

  $(area_ref).hover(function() {
    $(this).handleMouse().each(function() {
      $(this).highlight(defaults.color);
    } );
  },function() {
    if (!$(this).clicked){ // I try and access here
      $(this).handleMouse().each(function() {
        $(this).clearLight();
       } );
    }
  } );
  return $(this);
};
```

Comment: You have to create some kind of connection. You could save the index in [a data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) or manually bind click handlers for each object (not recommended)

Comment: Provide some code where you use `this.propertyName`

Comment: ahhh, I like the data attribute idea. I had completely forgotten about that. I'll give that a try now

Comment: How do you do the event binding? If it's from within a method of those MapArea objects, you should still be able to use 'this'.

Comment: I updated the question with one of my methods where the problem exists as an example of how I am using it. I am not an expert javascripter by any means. As far as my interpretation goes, I hoped that setup would work.

Comment: Since there's no direct link between the area_ref and the objects inside it, a data-attribute would indeed be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [data function](https://api.jquery.com/data/) of jQuery to bind an object to a DOM element. So you can do something like the following to store your objects:

```
$('#clickableElement1').data('mapArea', new MapArea(some passed variables));
```

And something like the following to retrieve an object given an event:

```
var mapArea = $(event.currentTarget).data('mapArea');
```